# get the value for ALT is we check to see if an actual ALT value is set, if not we use the caption and if no caption is set we use the title

Tags: loop, page-template

```
function custom_pic_alt( $attachment_ID ) {
    
      // Get ALT
    $thumb_alt = get_post_meta( $attachment_ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true );
    
    // No ALT supplied get attachment info
    if ( empty( $thumb_alt ) )
      $attachment = get_post( $attachment_ID );
    
    // Use caption if no ALT supplied
    if ( empty( $thumb_alt ) )
      $thumb_alt = get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id())->post_excerpt;
    
    // Use title if no caption supplied either
    if ( empty( $thumb_alt ) )
      $thumb_alt = get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id())->post_title;
    
    // Return ALT
    return esc_attr( trim( strip_tags( $thumb_alt ) ) );
 }
```

show result

```
<?php echo custom_pic_alt( 10 ); ?>
```

and i get same alt for all attachments.

Comment: What your question describes is not what your code says, what's the purpose of the `$attachment` variable? It never gets used, and then for some reason you ignore everything and use `get_post_thumbnail_id` instead

Comment: Are the titles of your attachments descriptions of the content of the images? If not, you're misusing the alt attribute and making your site inaccessible to many users. Having `alt="DSC_0290.JPG"` might stop certain validators from complaining, but you have not actually addressed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this'll work for you because I don't know if `$attachment_ID` in the function is returning anything at all... ...but assuming it is:

```
function custom_pic_alt( $attachment_ID ) {
    //var_dump( $attachment_ID ); //uncomment this and see if it even returns anything.
    $thumb_alt      = get_post_meta( $attachment_ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true );
    $thumb_caption  = wp_get_attachment_caption( $attachment_ID );
    $thumb_title    = get_the_title( $attachment_ID );

    if( !empty( $thumb_alt ) ) :
        $alt_text = $thumb_alt;
    elseif( empty( $thumb_alt) && !empty( $thumb_caption ) ) :
        $alt_text = $thumb_caption;
    elseif( empty( $thumb_alt ) && empty( $thumb_caption ) && !empty( $thumb_title ) ) :
        $alt_text = $thumb_title;
    else : 
        $alt_text = '';
    endif;  
    
    // Return ALT
    return esc_attr( trim( strip_tags( $alt_text ) ) );
}
```

You just get all three values and then run conditional checks to see if they're empty or not.

Comment: function custom_pic_alt( $attachment_ID = null ) { if ( is_null( $attachment_ID ) ) return false; // the rest of the function... }

Comment: I do not need the ALT, but the TITLE and it worked great for my theme. Thank you very much!